# What is the difference between setup project and setup wizard?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, setup-project, setup-wizard

For a winform application I have to create an installer project, here is what I have as choice:

[image]

What is the difference between Setup Project and Setup Wizard ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Setup Wizard will help automate the creation of one of the project types shown in the dialog.

The Setup Project option creates an installer for a Windows-based application.

See [Microsoft Learn: "How to: Create or Add a Setup Project"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/19x10e5c(v=vs.100))

Answer (score 13):

The **Setup Wizard** will use about 5 steps to lead you create any kind of `Setup Project/ Web Setup Project / Merge Module Project / CAB Project`,

And the **Setup Project** creates a Setup Project.

I make the screenshot of steps of **Setup Wizard** to create Setup Project:

1.Welcome Page

[image]

2.Choose `Create a setup for a Windosws application`, the other 3 options can create `Web Setup Project / Merge Module Project / CAB Project`

[image]

3.Choose project outputs to include, here will show other projects in the same solution for you to choose from

[image]

4.If you have other files to include, you can add here

[image]

5.Summary and check, click finish to create

[image]

6.The final create screen is same as directly create a **Setup Project**.

In fact, every steps in the **Setup Wizard** all can be set somewhere in the directly created **Setup Project**.

[image]